# Typescript ES5 Configuration

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, setup-project

I want to target ES5 so I setup in my Visual Studio project file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptIncludeComments>false</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind> 
 </PropertyGroup>
```

But now I am getting `error MSB6006: "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.` With ES3 I don't get the error.

Comment: What version of typescript is installed?

Comment: it is version 0.9.1.1

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well, if i get it figured out i will let you know

Comment: What does the output window say?

Comment: the whole output: `1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(74,5): error MSB6006: "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.`

Comment: Try turning on verbose logging in your build. That should give you more information about the error. http://sedodream.com/2008/06/16/ChangingBuildVerbosityInVisualStudio.aspx

Comment: 0.9.1.1 predates a lot of bug fixing and build support. It also predates the "spec lockdown" and has some incompatibilities with the final TypeScript syntax. If you can, you should probably upgrade your version of TypeScript, particularly to or past 1.0. It may take some upgrade work (particularly due to the default inferred type becoming ``{}`` rather than ``any``).

Comment: @zoidbergi Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: not sure, compare your project file to a clean project. delete the suo. Reinstall typescript/VS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard tsconfig.json file in project files tree (VS detect them).
BTW same way use for npm config package.json.